# GEOIP2 The value "*IP*" is not a valid IP address

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, geoip, geoip2

When ever we try to let google crawl our website we get several errors in sentry:

```
The value "213.55.176.155, 66.249.93.93" is not a valid IP address
```

or

```
The value "213.55.176.162, 66.102.9.18" is not a valid IP address.
```

The code error is coming from "$record  = $reader->city($ip);"

```
$reader = new Reader('GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
        $record  = $reader->city($ip);
       // $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $iso_code = $record->country->isoCode;
        $timezone = $record->location->timeZone;
```

We think its a AddressNotFoundException because the IP is not valid in geolite2 DB of maxmind.

Does anyone now how to avoid this error?

Comment: `$ip` contains 2 IP addresses; I could see that failing the "valid IP **address**" rule...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your string contains multiple IPs, so try splitting them and looping?

Something like:

```
$ips = explode(', ', $ip)
foreach(...) {
    ...
}
```